# enable vnc after virt-install

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, virt-install

I've created a virtual machine using virt-install with `graphics --none`. I want to enable vnc. I've tried

`virsh -c qemu:///system qemu-monitor-command vm171-SC-1 --hmp change vnc :3`

but it doesn't work

`virsh -c qemu:///system qemu-monitor-command vm171-SC-1 --hmp info vnc
Server: disabled`

How can I enable vnc after running virt-install? I don't want to install with vnc enabled (i.e --graphics vnc,listen=0.0.0.0,port=) is not an option because I want it to send its output to the same termnial that I am in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use virsh to  edit the domain xml and append the graphics element: `virsh edit <domain>`

Here's the xml snippet for vnc support

```
<graphics type='vnc' port='5901' autoport='yes' listen='0.0.0.0'>
  <listen type='address' address='0.0.0.0'/>
</graphics>
```